# Unit of Work pattern implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating an application with ASP.NET MVC and Entity framework code first. I am using repository and unit of work pattern with influence of from following link.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Here I have question about the implementation of Unit Of Work in that link unit of work is implemented via directly writing entities in class itself like.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private SchoolContext context = new SchoolContext();
    private GenericRepository<Department> departmentRepository;

    public GenericRepository<Department> DepartmentRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.departmentRepository == null)
            {
                this.departmentRepository = new GenericRepository<Department>(context);
            }
            return departmentRepository;
        }
    }

}
```

Do you think that implementation is good enough because every time I add/remove entities I need to change my Unit of work class. I believe that Unit of work should not be dependent on entities. Because in my application based on Client feedback we are going to frequently add/remove entities.

I may sound stupid but let me know your views on that.

Comment: Why do you feel you need a Unit of work?  Entity Framework is already an implementation of the Unit of Work pattern, and gives you all the functionality of it.  The only reason to implement your own unit of work is if the data access you have doesn't already implement it, or you need to abstract your data access to support different technologies, which is something that most people never need (YAGNI).  What's more, with EF6, you can now effectively mock EF so the Mocking reason doesn't apply anymore either.  Certainly, use a repository though.

Comment: Ef gives you change tracking entities through UOW. It gives you an ability for in-memory transactions(Unit) which can be CRUD. Like you said that your system has a great deal with entities, this is where EF benefits in the form of performance & consistency, your unit of work will be having ACID behavior. Here is [the article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/581487/Unit-of-Work-Design-Pattern "Unit of Work Design Pattern") you can refer for more info.

Comment: @Erik - So I think we don't need Unit of Work pattern here. Can you provide some kind of sample here.

Answer (score 23):

The Unit of Work pattern is already implemented in Entity Framework.

The DbContext is your Unit of Work.
Each IDbSet is a Repository.

```
using (var context = new SchoolContext())   // instantiate our Unit of Work
{
    var department = context.Departments.Find(id);
}
```

Comment: The point of having a separate unit of work and repository from EF is it allows you to replace the EF provider with something else. For example a fake mock provider while performing unit testing is much easier to implement if you all you have to mock is a single `Get(int)` call, mocking the exposed IDbSet object is much harder to do due to the much larger size of the interface.

Comment: Have you ever replaced your DB provider with something else?  In 15 years of software development I have never seen anyone do this, nor could I ever fathom a management team that would sign off on such a change.  Nevertheless, keeping your DB implementation out of your higher level code is a good idea and I agree with you.  However I'd just stay away from doing a full blown unit of work pattern and just create a new layer that does exactly what I'm doing in the code above.

Comment: I have replaced the DB provider with completely mocked implementation for stress testing and protocol testing in one highly distributed system. It was impossible to use real database because it was 100 times slower than the simulated database.

Comment: DbContext is not a unit of work.  It can only be considered a unit of work in  simple applications.  A unit of work is all work that needs to be done in a single transaction.  That could involve multiple db contexts, publishing to an async message bus, generating outgoing mail, etc.

Comment: @RyanLangton:    If DbContext is Unit of Work and IDbSet is Repository, Where do we need to have business transactions ? Like getting details (Department) from repository and saving in Unit of work and ( Logic of maintain log history, Who done this Transaction of adding Department, When its done, Does he has required role etc) and How to use same code from different presentation layer.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few flavors of the UnitOfWorkPattern.  The one you are describing is a show everything, there is a hide everything approach as well.  In the hide approach the unit of work references the DbContext.SaveChanges() method and nothing else; sounds like what you want.

```
public YourContext : DbContext, IContext{}

public interface IUnitOfWork{
   void Commit();
}

public UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork{
    private readonly IContext _context;

    //IOC should always inject the same instance of this, register it accordingly
    public UnitOfWork(IContext context){
        _context = context;
    }

    void Commit(){
           // try catch the validation exception if you want to return the validations this
           // way if your confident you've already validated you can put a void here or
           // return the intfrom save changes make sure you handle the disposing properly,
           // not going into that here you also may be doing other stuff here, have multiple
           // "contexts" to save in a single transaction or we have contextProcessors that
           // do stuff based on items in the context
          _context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

This leaves the issue of how you get your repositories into the classes that need them if you are not taking them from the UnitOfWork.  This is best handled by an IOC framework.  Again here there are a couple options.  Once is to register the UnitOfWork as a single instance per request and have it injected into your custom Repository class.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> Records();
    //other methods go here
}

public Repository : IRepository<T>
{
    private IContext _context;

    // same instance of context injected into the unit of work, this why when you Commit
    // everything will save, this can get tricky if you start adding Add, Update and stuff
    // but EF does have the support needed.
    public Repository(IContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
    }

    public Records()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }
}

public class SomeService : ISomeService{
   private readonly _myObjectRepository;

   public SomeService(IRepository<MyObject> myObjectRepository){
       _myObjectRepository = myObjectRepository;
   }
}
```

Personally I consider the IDbSet an sufficient abstraction so I no longer create repositories.  In
order to inject the IDbSets from the context though you need to register them as instances that you
extract from the context in your IOC setup.  This can be complex and depending on your skills you 
could find yourself in the situation where you have to register each IDbSet which I know you are trying to avoid.

What's nice about using the IDbSet is you have access to simple methods like Add and can avoid some of the more complex parts of working with Entity and DbEntity in a generic sense.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService {
    private readonly _myObjectSet;

    // requires specialized IOC configurations because you have to pull this instance from
    // the instance of the context, personally don't know how to do this with a single
    // registration so this has the same problem as having to add each new repository to the
    // unit of work.  In this case each new Entity I add to the context requires I add an IOC
    // registration for the type.

    public SomeService(IDbSet<MyObject> myObjectSet){
        _myObjectSet= myObjectSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: As per your answer I have implemented code like this -http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47879/unit-of-work-and-repository-with-entity-framework-6 is it good or not?

Comment: You should update your answer to show the IUnitOfWork being used by something.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the SchoolContext to the GenericRepository:

```
public GenericRepository<T>
{
    private SchoolContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
    }

    public Get(int id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

And use:

```
using(var context = new SchoolContext())
{
    var departmentRepository = new GenericRepository<Department>(context);
    var department = departmentRepository.Get(1);
}
```