# Refactoring code using Entity Framework 6 to follow TDD

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Right now, I'm on a task to refactor an ASP.Net MVC application that using EF6. Currently, the code use EF Designer to generate the entities (edmx file) and all of the logic bloated the controller.

I've read some article about TDD and EF6, and I know this question is similar to some others like

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47879/unit-of-work-and-repository-with-entity-framework-6
- [Unit of Work pattern implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111868/unit-of-work-pattern-implementation)

But most of it refer to "Code First" development. I'm also aware that EF6 has implement UnitOfWork internally, so my question is how do I structure my code so it will:

- Follow TDD practice (Testable Code)
- Moving all of the logic to another layer than Controllers

But still using the "Database first" development type. What pattern should I follow? All of the feedback would be really appreciate.

[Edited]
This is one of an action in current controller (right now it contain 500+ line of code)

```
public ActionResult ToggleProductPromoCodeIsActive(string promoCode, string productID, string countryCode)
    {
        var isActive = ToggleProductPromoCodeIsActive(promoCode, productID, countryCode);
        return Json(new { isActive = isActive }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

public ActionResult AddPromoCodeProperties(string promoCode, DateTime beginningDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, bool isActive, int? length, string countryCode, short? maximumRenewals)
    {
        int id = AddPromoCodeProperties(promoCode, beginningDateTime, endDateTime, isActive, length, countryCode, maximumRenewals);
        if (id != 0)
        {
            return Json(new { message = "Promo code properties have been succesfully added", id = id, promoCode = promoCode }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { message = "Failed: The same promo code with the same country code has existed", promoCode = promoCode }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }


    // ----- Another line of code

    private int AddProductPromoCode(string promoCode, double discountPercentage, string productID, bool isActive, string countryCode, string paymentPageText, string finalProductID)
    {
        using (var provisioningContext = new ProvisioningEntities())
        {
            var productPromoCode = provisioningContext.ProductPromoCodes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.code == promoCode && x.productID == productID && x.countryCode == countryCode);
            if (productPromoCode == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    productPromoCode = new ProductPromoCode();
                    productPromoCode.code = promoCode;
                    productPromoCode.discountPercentage = discountPercentage;
                    productPromoCode.productID = productID;
                    productPromoCode.isActive = isActive;
                    productPromoCode.countryCode = countryCode;
                    productPromoCode.paymentPageText = paymentPageText;
                    productPromoCode.finalProductID = finalProductID;
                    provisioningContext.ProductPromoCodes.Add(productPromoCode);
                    provisioningContext.SaveChanges();
                    return productPromoCode.ID;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ToggleProductPromoCodeIsActive(string promoCode, string productID, string countryCode)
    {
        using (var provisioningContext = new ProvisioningEntities())
        {
            var productPromoCode = provisioningContext.ProductPromoCodes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.code == promoCode && x.productID == productID && x.countryCode == countryCode);
            productPromoCode.isActive = !productPromoCode.isActive;
            provisioningContext.Entry(productPromoCode).State = EntityState.Modified;
            provisioningContext.SaveChanges();
            return productPromoCode.isActive;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Regarding controller bloat, Jimmy Bogard has several posts on the CQRS pattern. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/05/05/cqrs-with-mediatr-and-automapper/

Comment: This video is about Rails, but I think it's relevant to what your are doing, I found it while browsing Robert Martin's (Uncle Bob) blog https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tg5RFeSfBM4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

Implement a repository for each entity in the context. If you have a set of similar operations that are done to all entities (for example, GetAll, GetByID, Create, Update, Delete), you could define a common interface which will be your starting point. Then, all the repositories will implement their own interface which would inherit from that one. You would use generics to accomplish this:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T>
{
    T GetByID(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Create(T element);
    // and so on...
}
```

This will provide you a couple of advantages:

1) You centralize the more important operations in a base interface, and each repository interface will inherit from that one.

2) Since all the repositories implement their own interfaces, you can create mock implementations that will help you with TDD.

3) You can now decouple the interface from the actual implementations and implement dependency injection. There are a ton of IoC containers that are very easy to use. You could use Microsoft's Unity, which is very easy to use (For example, in Unity you can solve which type implements which interface through the web.config or the app.config).

So at this point you would have your data access layer divided into the following components:

- Database Context (where you set the dbsets, the configurations, mappings, seeds)
- Repositories (the actual implementations that use the dbcontext)
- Repositories interfaces (that you would treat as the actual contracts to operate the database).
- Mock repositories

For the second part, you would have to elaborate more about the bloated logic in your controllers, since the actions and methods could be having too much responsibility in their hands. With the info you provided, I would suggest to follow the S.O.L.I.D. principles.

**EDIT:**

Now I see the code you pasted.

In this particular example you provided, implementing a repository for the `ProductPromoCodes`entity will take the logic related to deal with the entity out of the controller into the repository and the data provider layers.

First, define the repo interface like this (since I see these are the operations that you need to do in the `provisioningContext`

```
public interface IProductPromoCodeRepository
{
    // You can see that these are similar to the methods that the IBaseRepository interface defines, so you can actually make this one inherit from it.
    ProductPromoCode Get(string code, string id, string country);
    void Create(ProductPromoCode item);
    void Update(ProductPromoCode item);
}
```

Then, write the implementation (a class called `ProductPromoCodeRepository` which inherits the repository interface). The code of each of these methods will more or less like it is now in the private methods of the controller, and the `provisioningContext` will be a member of this class that implements them, so the controller only needs to deal with the `ProductPromoCodeRepository`.

You can even encapsulate this logic

```
productPromoCode.isActive = !productPromoCode.isActive;
provisioningContext.Entry(productPromoCode).State = EntityState.Modified;
provisioningContext.SaveChanges();
```

In its own method in the repository if you want, so in the controller you would need to do is use the value that this method returns.

After all that, these two actions would be something like the following:

```
public ActionResult ToggleProductPromoCodeIsActive(string promoCode, string productID, string countryCode)
{
    var isActive = _productPromoCodeRepository.ToogleActive(promoCode, productID, countryCode);// This encapsulates the three lines of code from above...
    return Json(new { isActive = isActive }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult AddPromoCodeProperties(string promoCode, DateTime beginningDateTime, DateTime endDateTime, bool isActive, int? length, string countryCode, short? maximumRenewals)
{
    var productPromoCode = _productPromoCodeRepository.Get(promoCode, productID/*I don't know where do you get this value*/, countryCode);
    if(productPromoCode != null)
        return Json(new { message = "Failed: The same promo code with the same country code has existed", promoCode = promoCode }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    productPromoCode = new ProductPromoCode();
    productPromoCode.code = promoCode;
    productPromoCode.discountPercentage = discountPercentage;
    productPromoCode.productID = productID;
    productPromoCode.isActive = isActive;
    productPromoCode.countryCode = countryCode;
    productPromoCode.paymentPageText = paymentPageText;
    productPromoCode.finalProductID = finalProductID;
    _productPromoCodeRepository.Create(productPromoCode);
    // you can actually move all these lines above to the repo with another overload for the Create method that takes all the parameters.

    // Here you can be sure the item didn't exist before in the database, but you would have to deal with errors in the creation and return the proper error message.
    return Json(new { message = "Promo code properties have been succesfully added", id = productPromoCode.id, promoCode = productPromoCode.code }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: Right now, the controller full of business logic and data access code all at once. In one action right now you'll have a code for accessing dbcontext to retrieve the data or CUD process and do other stuff as well with it.

Comment: I don't know if you are allowed, but could you post an action method as an example? or maybe one whole controller? I would like to take a look at the  scope of the variables, how many dependencies the controller has in non internal or protected types, etc.